# JSF Security Libraries

Tags: security, jsf

What technologies and libraries are available for JSF security? I want to protect my admin pages of a JSF application from public access.

Comment: JSF by itself does not provide or cater for application access control and authorization. I'd recommend you start out with stock JEE security before exploring third-party libs(spring, shiro etc). You can start with these tutorials http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjiie.html, http://wiki.netbeans.org/SecureJavaEE6App(ignore the LDAP config section of the tutorial) and this http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a rather difficult question but these days I would go for [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) or [Apache Shiro](https://shiro.apache.org/). In case you are not using Spring, I would take a look at Shiro. It's pretty easy to set this up and also to use. There are also few tutorials, like [this one](http://balusc.blogspot.cz/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html) from BalusC.

Another option are [Realms](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html) which can have container specific (Tomcat, Glassfish, ...) settings which would make them not portable. You could also use a [Phase Listener](http://devgrok.blogspot.cz/2009/07/access-control-using-phaselistener.html) which can be very neat way to secure small projects (if your application is going to be small, I would go for this option). There are other frameworks and workarounds too, try to google little more about Java EE security and you will see.

Comment: Realms are not portable? I beg to differ. What you might say is there might be container-specific configs for realms. Is there a JEE app server or servlet container that doesn't provide realms (JAAS)?

Comment: I meant these container-specific settings, I will update my answer. Thanks for notice

Comment: Thanks @Petr Mensik. I have not used any of these, but I'll try to give it some research time and may give Shiro a try.

Comment: There's also Seam3 Security module.

Comment: @Petr thanks for introducing apache shiro to me. I did an in depth research on that and seems to fit my project. I am just facing an error implementing that. The error is: "Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener." Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks again. I am opening another question for this problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use spring:

Add spring security dependencies in your `pom.xml`, then change springSecurity-taglibs.xml (add function names like areAnyGranted)

Then, in your `web.xml`, add the context param:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springSecurity-taglibs.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

After that add roles in your applicationContext-security.xml

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/admin.xhtml" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

Comment: please correct the answer. And this is a very detailed answer for ONE of the possible solutions.... One cannot accept this answer since it is not explicitly the only answer